# Comparing between one value and a range of values in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array that looks like this:

```
a = [[  0   0   0   0   0  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75]
     [  4   5   6   7   8  29  34  39  44  49  54  59  64  69  74 250]]
```

and I also have another 1D array that looks like this:

```
age_array = [45,46,3,7]
```

is there a way to verify that the values in `age_array` are within the range of the 2 values in the first column of `a` and if not then move on to the next column? For example,

```
if a[0: , :] <= age_array[i] <= a[1:, :]
      return True
else: return False
```

Comment: So you want to know if 45 is between 0 and 75, and then also if it is between 4 and 250?

Comment: Or do you want to know if 45 is between 0 and 4?

Comment: I want to know if its between 0 and 4 if it is return True if not, check the next values in the a array

Comment: Do you need to be able to expand this for arrays with more than 2 entries?  If you are only comparing based on an array with 2 subarrays, check my updated answer

Comment: based only on 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if each entry in the age array is between the `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]`

```
a = [[0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  50,  55,  60,  65,  70,  75],
     [4,   5,   6,   7,   8,  29,  34,  39,  44,  49,  54,  59,  64,  69,  74, 250]]

age_array = [45,46,3,7]

dct = {}

for age in age_array:
    for i in range(len(a[0])):
        if a[0][i] <= age and age <= a[1][i]:
            print(str(age) + ' is between ' + str(a[0][i]) + ' and ' + str(a[1][i]))
            break
```

This outputs:

```
45 is between 45 and 49
46 is between 45 and 49
3 is between 0 and 4
7 is between 0 and 7
```

Comment: this one compares only the age_array value with the first column, if the first range check return False I want it to pass to the next column

Comment: This makes so much more sense.  I'll update my answer

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can convert both the arrays into sets and then check if age_array set is a subset of a set.

Unfortunately I cannot post answer as your first array is not properly formatted

Answer (score -1):

Very simple to understand but it might look quite ugly.

```
value=[]
for x in range(len(a)):
    for xx in range(len(a[x])):
        for xxx in range(len(b)):
            if a[x][xx]==b[xxx]:
                value.append("true")
            else:
                value.append("false") 


for a in value:
    if a=="true":
        #it falls in the category
```